# php errors notices warnings truncated

Tags: php

I have PHP set up for E_ALL, so usually receive `notice/warning/error` info in form:

**Notice:** Undefined variable: var in **path\to\my\file** on line **1**

Now this has suddenly changed: my application is kicking them out in format

**Noticepath\to\my\file1**

i.e. no formatting, no description of the notice, just error-class, file-path and line number concatenated together

As far as I can tell nothing has changed with settings etc
If I do a simple test script the correct verbose format is still being produced
e.g.

```
echo $var;
```

where var is undefined

It just started happening this morning on an application that I am currently working on, which was not having this problem earlier, where as far as I can see nothing changed that should impact this

I haven't been able to find any remotely similar problems raised previously here or anywhere else so any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: How are you viewing there notices? In the browser? If yes, check the source to make sure its not just some css/js interfering with the display

Comment: What does the apache (?) error log say?

Comment: add code which related to your question as well

Comment: I'm using IIS: can't find anything relevant in the log that would obviously indicate strangeness (but it is pretty cryptic).  Yep; viewing in browser but not using any css/js of my own, just plain ole php

Comment: Hi Abdulla; thanks but I think my point is that I have no idea what part of my code could have changed this and the overall application is quite large; it's more a question of whether anybody has seen anything similar and may know what causes this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

OK: Fixed it. Thanks for help guys

Simple error - it was just the unexpected outcome in terms of impact on error reporting that threw me.

FYI: I had a variable called '$direct'; I missed the '$' in an if statement, and it looks like 'direct' in that context is meaningful